# 7Digit Display counting bug

Tags: c, arm, embedded, qemu

I am trying to fix the bug in my code - I have 7Digit display, which must count up from 0 to 99 when button is not pressed, or count down from 99 to 0 when button is pressed.
I have the issue with counting up, the issue happens, when the display must show numbers as 10,20,30 etc. While countin it up, after number 09 there is 00 instead of 10, after 19 there is 10 instead of 20 etc.
I am attching below a fragment of code responsible for counting up and down:

```
void Refresh_Display() {
    AT91C_BASE_PIOB->PIO_CODR = A|B|C|D|E|F|G;
}
void set_Number(int number) {
    AT91C_BASE_PIOB->PIO_SODR = LEFTDIGIT;
    AT91C_BASE_PIOB->PIO_CODR = RIGHTDIGIT;
    Refresh_Display();
    Display_Number(number%10);
    delay(5000);
    AT91C_BASE_PIOB->PIO_SODR = RIGHTDIGIT;
    AT91C_BASE_PIOB->PIO_CODR = LEFTDIGIT;
    Refresh_Display();
    Display_Number(number/10);
    delay(5000);
}

void countdown(int i) {
    while(1) {
        if(i<=0) {
            i = 99;
        }
        set_Number(i);
        i--;
        if(!BP1_Status) {
            counter = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void countup(int i) {
  while(1) {
        i++;
        if(i>=99) {
            i = 0;
        }
        set_Number(i);
        if(BP1_Status) {
            counter = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    Port_init();
    Button_init();

    while(1) {
        for (volatile int i=0;i<100;i++) {
            if(BP1_Status) {
                countdown(counter);
            } else if (!BP1_Status) {
                countup(counter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First off I wouldn't use while(1).  Try to convert it to a control break. That might be something like while(!BP1_Status).  it just isn't good practice in coding.  Have you single stepped through the code to see what the values are as you go through it?  That's your best to start with.

Comment: Why do you put a delay 5000 between the display of the 2 digits ? The right digit will always be displayed before the left one. So when count down it may look ok but not when counting up.

Comment: Comment from @PtitXav is correct. After 19 first the 'units' digit 9 changes so it reads 10 and then the 'tens' unit 1 changes so it reads 20. Remove one delay and double the time of the other delay.

Comment: I removed one delay and doubled The second one,but Then it show only one display with one digit.

Comment: @Dale changing The loop as while(!BP_Status) is not making any difference while running The code

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution for that problem:
In the ARM processor AT91SAM9263 there are registers PIO_CODR and PIO_SODR. The first one register is refreshing data, the second one Sets the data to be driven on the I/O line.
I have swapped the method of display the numbers on two 7Segment Displays. On the left, there are displayed, the decimal numbers are displayed as `number/10` and the units as `numbers%10`to receive 0 digit on second display while showing 10 or 20 value.

```
void set_Number(int number) {
    AT91C_BASE_PIOB->PIO_CODR = LEFTDIGIT;
    AT91C_BASE_PIOB->PIO_SODR = RIGHTDIGIT;
    Refresh_Display();
    Display_Number(number/10);
    delay(5000);
    AT91C_BASE_PIOB->PIO_CODR = RIGHTDIGIT;
    AT91C_BASE_PIOB->PIO_SODR = LEFTDIGIT;
    Refresh_Display();
    Display_Number(number%10);
    delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: It's still a bad solution, now it fails when counting down! @PtitXav already said it: Remove the first delay, or even better remove both from `set_Number()` and add the delay elsewhere